# What do we mean by electrostatics when charges are in motion?

Tags: electrostatics, terminology, definition, approximations

Charges are always in motion, so what exactly does electrostatics refers to, is it a hypothetical concept or does it hold any sense in particle quantum physics?

Comment: Charges are not always in motion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electrostatics deals with simpler problems where we assume all the charges are stationary to make calculations more simplified; in some cases, the charges are nearly stationary so these calculations can be useful. Electrodynamics is a larger field that deals with collections of charges in motion.